# Justify an approximation of the first few decimals of $\int_1^\infty(\int_0^1\frac{dx}{-1+x^3+y^2})dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

This morning I wondered about how to calculate an approximation (I think thus that our integral has no a known indefinite integral, at least for some of the terms in the integrand) of $$\int_1^\infty\left(\int_0^1\frac{dx}{-1+x^3+y^2}\right)dy.\tag{1}$$

I would like to know if is it possible to get and justify an approximation using analysis (only is required two or three right decimal digits, and after the theoretical justification you can invoke calculations using your computer). I know that $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dy}{-1+x^3+y^2}=\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^3-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3-1}},$$
and I don't know if it is a good idea to use the Taylor series of the inverse tangent function here.

Second, if we calculate the closed-form of the inner integral in $(1)$ I think that also should be difficult to get approximation using Taylor series.

> **Question.** Provide a reasoning to get the integer part and the first two decimal digits (after the decimal point) of $(1)$. **Many thanks.**

It is obvious that our integral is greater than $1$.

Comment: First, why not download [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and compute the integral numerically yourself? Second, what does it mean to "justify" a numerical result?

Comment: Many thanks @AntonioVargas for your attention and feedback. My problem is that I'm a bad programmer, that is the fear to use software  in mathematics. On the other hand I am asking with the words *justify*, and explanation using analysis, by means of inequalities, theorems, series expansions...

Comment: With the help of google I'm sure you could figure out how to integrate it.

Comment: Do you think that has closed-form @AntonioVargas ?

Comment: I have no reason to believe so. Then again, I have been surprised many times by some of the integrals which have been calculated on this site.

Comment: As user243301 says, it is only normal to justify the error when approximating, and I disagree with Antonio, there is no a priori reason to rely on google or other software, if it's not to check results or have an idea.

Comment: OP is asking to justify numerical methods only for two decimals, with reasoning not computing. This involves an upper bound for errors, for instance.

Comment: My idea arises from the belief that one can to get a result for previous integral using analysis for few decimals. Many thanks @Tal-Botvinnik

Comment: What does that mean? @user243301

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik You've got to be kidding me. If there is a supposed dire need to rigorously approximate this particular integral to within $10^{-2}$ then I would love to know, because then I am **absolutely certain** this post would be an example of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231209). The question should either ask for a rigorous closed form or for a non-rigorous numerical evaluation using computing software, demonstrating attempts at either. Its current form is misguided and we should not be encouraging it.

Comment: Many thaks @amWhy

Comment: @user243301  Just edited the title to keep the vertical space consistent with most other titles, as they appear on the front page.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @AntonioVargas I am asking many of my questions as an amateur mathematician. My question here was if we can get an approximation of the integral using analysis (
another discussion is whether my approach or attempts are poors). I'm not a professional mathematician. Any case I'm sorry.

Comment: @user243301 my point is that I believe it is misguided to ask for such a thing. Did you read the link about X-Y problems?

Comment: I read the first answer, and I am going to read it, I don't want dirsturb to any user in this site, and I know that sometimes my behavior can be disruptive. This my post was downvoted two times, thus we can wait what happen with my post. Many thanks @AntonioVargas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to expand the integrand of the double integral and integrate that term by term. We can write this as a geometric series:

$$f(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1-x^3\right)^n}{y^{2n+2}}$$

The integral over $x$ can be evaluated by substituting $u = 1-x^3$, the integral over $u$ then becomes $\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}u^n (1-u)^{-2/3}du$, this can be expressed in terms of a beta function: $\frac{1}{3} \dfrac{n!\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)!}{(n+\frac{1}{3})!} = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)! \dfrac{n!}{(n+\frac{1}{3})!}$

The integral over $y$ yields a factor of $\dfrac{1}{2n +1}$, therefore the integral can be written as :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)! \frac{n!}{(2n+1)(n+\frac{1}{3})!}\tag{1}$$

The summation converges very slowly, but it's easy to deal with that by treating the tail of the summation using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorials and then applying the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to approximate the summation over the tail. Note that Stirling's formula can itself be derived using the Euler–Maclaurin formula.

Stirling's formula yields the following expansion for the summand in (1):

$$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)! \frac{n^{-1/3}}{(2n+1)}\left(1-\frac{2}{9 n} +\frac{7}{81 n^2}-\frac{70}{2187 n^3}+\frac{182}{19683 n^4}-\frac{364}{177147 n^5}+\cdots\right)\tag{2}$$

We can now sum the first, say, $20$ terms of the summation in (1) and then approximate the summation from $n = 21$ to infinity by replacing the summand in (1) by the expansion (2), and then compute that summation of the tail, term by term by applying the Euler–Maclaurin formula to each term. This yields the result $2.30112685455\cdots$ for the summation, where the given $11$ decimals are correct. With more terms of the summation combined with more terms of the Euler–Maclaurin formula it's easy to get a large number of decimals.

Comment: Many thanks this morning I am going to study your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know functions which are much more pleasant to expand as Taylor series around $x=0$ than $$f=\frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^3-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}$$ but a CAS gave
$$f=\frac{1}{2} (2 \log (2)-3 \log (x))+\frac{1}{4} x^3 (-3 \log (x)-1+2 \log
   (2))+\frac{1}{32} x^6 (-18 \log (x)-7+12 \log (2))+\frac{1}{192} x^9 (-90 \log
   (x)-37+60 \log (2))+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ which can write
$$f=-\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3 x^3}{4}+\frac{9 x^6}{16}+\frac{15 x^9}{32}+O\left(x^{12}\right) \right)\log(x)+$$ $$\left(1+\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{3 x^6}{8}+\frac{5 x^9}{16}+O\left(x^{12}\right) \right)\log(2)-$$ $$\left(\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{7 x^6}{32}+\frac{37 x^9}{192}+O\left(x^{12}\right) \right) $$ in which the coefficients reveal some interesting patterns; however, these coefficients vary very slowly and let then suppose a very slow convergence for the integral.

The only "problematic" integral is $$\int_0^1x^n\log(x)\,dx=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\qquad \text{if} \qquad \Re(n)>-1$$ Using the above expansion and this last result, we find
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^3-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}\,dx=\frac{68209+56910 \log (2)}{47040}\approx 2.28861$$ while the numerical integration of the double integral would give $\color{red}{2.30109}$.

Adding the next term to the expansion would lead to $$\frac{61016077+52186680 \log (2)}{42398720}\approx 2.29227$$
Adding the next term to the expansion would lead to $$\frac{7763990653+6763367520 \log (2)}{5427036160}\approx 2.29444$$
Adding the next term to the expansion would lead to $$\frac{8368328064511+7394510017440 \log (2)}{5877480161280}\approx 2.29585$$

**Edit**

Because $\lim_{x\to 0} \, f =\infty$ but $\lim_{x\to 1} \, f =1$, we can expect that the numerical integration will have some difficulties. To show it, we considered the two integrals
$$g_1=\int_{10^{-k}}^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^3-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}\,dx \qquad \text{and} \qquad g_2=\int_0^{1-{10^{-k}}} \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^3-1}\right)}{\sqrt{x^3-1}}\,dx $$ Below are reported the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & g_1 & g_2 \\
 1 & 1.73637407698714 & 2.19584451172401 \\
 2 & 2.21011782123402 & 2.29107658640121 \\
 3 & 2.28857207445230 & 2.30012635428588 \\
 4 & 2.29952598877903 & 2.30102684955243 \\
 5 & 2.30093222130697 & 2.30111685450269 \\
 6 & 2.30110392707843 & 2.30112585455219 \\
 7 & 2.30112421944302 & 2.30112675455269 \\
 8 & 2.30112655626838 & 2.30112684455269 \\
 9 & 2.30112682127567 & 2.30112685355269 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

May be, it would have been simpler to make the expansion around $x=1$ to get for example
$$f=1-y+\frac{4 y^2}{5}-\frac{62 y^3}{105}+\frac{3 y^4}{7}-\frac{123
   y^5}{385}+\frac{1256 y^6}{5005}-\frac{1044 y^7}{5005}+\frac{15429
   y^8}{85085}+O\left(y^{9}\right)$$ where $y=x-1$ and integrate from $-1$ to $0$.

For an expansion up to $O\left(y^{n+1}\right)$, the results would have been
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{result} \\
 10 & 2.28861 \\
 20 & 2.29585 \\
 30 & 2.29848 \\
 40 & 2.29930 \\
 50 & 2.29976 \\
 60 & 2.30014 \\
 70 & 2.30032 \\
 80 & 2.30045 \\
 90 & 2.30058 \\
 100 & 2.30065
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @user243301. You are welcome ! One more term would give $\approx 2.29683$, another one $\approx 2.29754$, another one $\approx 2.29807$, another one $\approx 2.29848$. This is incredibly slow !